# Why changing locking mode from Automatic to Delayed doesn't solve my hanging issue?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-administration, oracleforms

I have an Oracle form (F1) with a databse data-block on it, this data-block has been built from table T1 (for example). I also have a package (P1) which tries to update the table T1.

When my users open the form (even without making any changes in it), the process would hang untill the users leave the form. P1 is run from Application Manager.

I changed the locking-mode on the forms from "automatic" till "delayed", but it doesn't solve my issue. Does anyone have an idea?!

many thanks!

Comment: Even with "automatic" the form shouldn't lock the records until you click into a field (e.g. to start editing). I'd suspect something else is happening, e.g. in a form trigger. Also, have you determined what the process is waiting for? i.e. are you sure it's waiting on a row lock?

Comment: When the form is opened, the control of the program goes to the database data-block. I monitored the database. it waits for the same table which is on the form. But I am think something is happening in one of the program units, or other triggers on the form.

Comment: One thing you could do is put an `ON-LOCK` trigger on the form with some debug message or popup, which will alert you if/when a lock is being taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a cursor with "for update nowait". Removing this, solved my problem.